# How to match FK bone to IK bone via script?

Tags: scripting, rigging, bones

I'm trying to make an IK to FK script, so I would like to have the FK bones align with the IK bones. What would be a good way to go about it?

I tried doing something like this:

```
upperArmFK.matrix = upperArmIK.matrix

forearmFK.matrix = forearmIK.matrix

handFK.matrix = handIK.matrix
```

But it would only align the upper IK and FK bones and not the forearm and hand bone.

Before applying my script:
[image]

After applying:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is described in part in the ["Gotchas"](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#no-updates-after-setting-values) section of the manual, here, 3.0 but it applies to 2.8 and 2.9 as well.

You need to call `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` after each matrix copy.

In addition it is safer to copy the matrix than to assign from it, so your code fragment should be

```
upperArmFK.matrix = upperArmIK.matrix.copy()
bpy.context.view_layer.update()

forearmFK.matrix = forearmIK.matrix.copy()
bpy.context.view_layer.update()

handFK.matrix = handIK.matrix.copy()
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

*unless*  your code fragment exists inside of a method that has `context` as an argument.  If it does, drop the `bpy.` from the above.